# How to show website is not aligned?

Tags: css, optimization, graphics, png

Is there a way to show my webmaster the "learn more" boxes aren't aligned and need to be adjusted a few pixels up or down in the CSS file? My webmaster cant see the misalignments.

See  "learn more" boxes for edification. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Take a screenshot, maximize (without interpolation: integer zoom with nearest-neighbour), send to his email address with big red angry arrows pointing at his shameful mistakes for all of the world to see and laugh at.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the developer tools in your browser.

For Internet Explorer:

1. Press **F12**.
2. Select the DOM Explorer (press **Ctrl+1**).
3. Select Element (press **Ctrl+B**).
4. Mouse over the elements and you can see the grid lines of elements on the page.

Google Chrome has similar features.

BTW, I don't see the icons are misaligned. Perhaps you need to refresh your browser.

[image]

Comment: I second this the icons are aligned...

Comment: Hi Rick Rainey & vimes1984 I meant the "learn more" boxes not the icons. I went ahead and used the steps above and am struggling to make a proper assessment on whether the "learn more" boxes are aligned. Several of my clients have mentioned they are misaligned. If the text is all blue then it indicates alignment? Thank you both for your time. Regards

Comment: OK, yes, I do see that. You should have used the "learn more" URL (http://economichedge.com/about-us/our-approach/) in your initial question.  The icons shown on that page are all part of a single image so the strategy I showed in my answer won't work in this case. But, seriously, it's a no-brainer to see the arrows are misaligned and I suspect that your web designer probably isn't clear what you are referring to. Be very specific about where your concern is and I'll bet you can get it taken care of.

Comment: That's not my question. I asked a straightforward question. I asked for a tool to prove to my webmaster the "learn more" boxes are not aligned. I made an edit but still doesn't change the question overall.

Comment: From your question: "adjusted a few pixels up or down in the CSS file".  What you are really seeking is a tool that can identify misalignments of elements "in the PNG file".  So, instead of tagging your question with "html" and "css", perhaps "png" and "graphics" would get you the answer you are seeking.